# Using Multi head CNN and merging for the input to RNNs for time series prediction

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, recurrent-neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to merge inputs from multiple CNN and take that as an input for RNN model.It is basically a CRNN with multiple CNN head.
I have 3-time series, I want to build 3 separate CNNs over these series, merge them and then use them as an input for RNN.
I have written the below code but it is not working for me.
Kindly help with this code. I will be highly obliged.

```
series1 = Sequential()
series1.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(3,2,activation='relu',padding='same',input_shape=(n_steps,n_features))))
series1.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,padding='valid',strides=2)))
series1.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
series2 = Sequential()
series2.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(3,2,activation='relu',padding='same',input_shape=(n_steps,n_features))))
series2.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,padding='valid',strides=2)))
series2.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
series3 = Sequential()
series3.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(3,2,activation='relu',padding='same',input_shape=(n_steps,n_features))))
series3.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,padding='valid',strides=2)))
series3.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
merged = Concatenate([series1,series2,series3])
final_model=Sequential()
final_model.add(merged)
final_model.add(SimpleRNN(5,return_sequences=True))
final_model.add(SimpleRNN(3))
output= Dense(1170)(final_model)

model= Model(inputs=[series1,series2,series3],outputs=output)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what's not working for you? what issues or errors are you facing

Comment: In this architecture, I am getting the error as the final_model does not have a shape component. I also wanted to know if this architecture is correct for the task I want to do.

Comment: Then add a shape component, your `input_shape` will be the shape of samples in `merged`. You should also try functional API for things that have branches/ensembles of models as that is easier IMO